# Using dplyr::case_when to conditionally change the value of a factored vaiable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that requires extensive data cleaning. Some of my variables are already factors. Some of the values of the factored variable I know to be incorrect; however, the levels of the factor are valid.

Yes, I could have converted the factored variable back to character and then re-factored when done with data cleaning --- but then I wouldn't have learned something.

```
library(dplyr)
## Create minimal reproducible example
min_re <- tibble(i = seq(1:10), my_letters = factor(substring("statistics", 1:10, 1:10), levels = letters))
```

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
       i my_letters
   <int> <fct>     
 1     1 s         
 2     2 t         
 3     3 a         
 4     4 t         
 5     5 i         
 6     6 s         
 7     7 t         
 8     8 i         
 9     9 c         
10    10 s
```

The first `s` in `statistics` is the wrong value. I want to replace the first `s` with an `x`, i.e., `xtatistics`
My first attempt:

```
min_re2 <- min_re %>%
  mutate(
    my_letters = case_when(
      my_letters == "s" & i == 1 ~ "x",
      TRUE ~ my_letters
    )
  )
```

Resulting error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `my_letters = case_when(my_letters == "s" & i == 1 ~ "x", TRUE
  ~ my_letters)`.
Caused by error in `` names(message) <- `*vtmp*` ``:
! 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Yet, this works:

```
min_re$my_letters[which(min_re$my_letters == "s" & min_re == 1)] <- "x"
min_re
```

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
       i my_letters
   <int> <fct>     
 1     1 x         
 2     2 t         
 3     3 a         
 4     4 t         
 5     5 i         
 6     6 s         
 7     7 t         
 8     8 i         
 9     9 c         
10    10 s
```

Why does the base r method work when changing a value of a factored variable but not `dplyr::case_when`? Is there a coercion that the base r method performs that `dplyr::case_when` is unwilling/unable to perform (e.g., character to factor)?

Is there a more elegant dplyr-ish way of changing values of already factored variables? Think data cleaning not necessarily re-leveling. There are some observations where `s` should remain `s`.

If new levels would be introduced, how does this affect `case_when`. Does `forcats` and `case_when` play nice?

Comment: `case_when` or `if_else` requires type matching as well for all arguments

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

(Yes, much easier to switch back to character, finish data cleaning, then refactor.)

In `case_when` present the changed value (right-hand side) as a factor with all the requisite levels.

```
library(dplyr)

min_re <- tibble(i = seq(1:10), my_letters = factor(substring("statistics", 1:10, 1:10), levels = letters))

min_re2 <- min_re %>%
  mutate(
    my_letters = case_when(
      my_letters == "s" & i == 1 ~ factor("x", levels = letters),
      TRUE ~ my_letters
    )
  )
```

```
> min_re2
# A tibble: 10 x 2
       i my_letters
   <int> <fct>     
 1     1 x         
 2     2 t         
 3     3 a         
 4     4 t         
 5     5 i         
 6     6 s         
 7     7 t         
 8     8 i         
 9     9 c         
10    10 s
```